# where is the error?

Tags: python, scripting

In this python script:

```
import bpy

import math

 # Place the reference of the selected 3D object in a variable

mon_objet = bpy.context.object

" We fix the object to the desired position "

mon_objet.location[0] = 2.2

mon_objet.location[1] = 0

frame_num = 0




entre_chaque_keyframe = 1

bpy.context.scene.frame_start = 0

bpy.context.scene.frame_end = 135000


for n in range(0,6300):

    x=4.4*math.cos(n)/(math.exp(50*n)+math.exp(-50*n))

    y=4.4*math.sin(n)/(math.exp(50*n)+math.exp(-50*n))

    z=2.2*(math.exp(50*n)-math.exp(-50*n))/(math.exp(50*n)+math.exp(-50*n))


    # We are on the right frame, frame_num is 0 at the beginning

    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frame_num)

    #We create a location keyframe

    mon_objet.location=(x,y,z)

    bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert_menu(type='Location')


    # We increase the value of the next frame to fix

    frame_num = frame_num+entre_chaque_keyframe
```

my goal is to insert a position key at each new location of the object.
The successive positions of the object are in a spherical helix;
In general, this kind of script worked very well (no error) for other parametric equations but here I do not see the error.
The python console says:
"syntax error: bpy.context.scene.frame_set (frame_num)"
Why ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the closing bracket here at the end:

```
z=2.2*(math.exp(50*n)-math.exp(-50*n))/(math.exp(50*n)+math.exp(-50*n)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Where to begin**

As pointed out there was a syntax error with a missing brace.

Added to that

Blender uses [radians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) as a unit of rotation. Stepping 1 radian every frame is equivalent of approx 57 degrees (`math.degrees(1)`) each frame, probably not what you want.

`math.exp` is going to grow exponentially and quite likely give math domain errors.  Try crunching `math.exp(50 * 6300)` into your python interpreter and see if it gives a result.  Might need `numpy` or use 1 for `(a - b) / (a + b)` when `a` gets large.  Or re-visit your equations for a spiral.

Break down large  formulas into smaller parts.

There is no need to either call the anim insert menu operator (IMO Never use this in a script) , consider that more of use in UI.  Use [`keyframe_insert(...)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.bpy_struct.html?highlight=keyframe_insert#bpy.types.bpy_struct.keyframe_insert) method of the ID object.  Can also pass the frame taking away the need to set frame each iteration too.

Below is somethat of a clean up of your script. Notice it will throw a `NaN` (not a number) result for z after a number of frames.

```
import bpy

from math import exp, sin, cos, radians
from mathutils import Vector

ob = bpy.context.object

entre_chaque_keyframe = 1

frame = 0

for n in range(3600):
    alpha = radians(n)
    m = 0.01
    a = exp(m * alpha)
    b = 1 / a
    c = 2.2 / (a + b)


    v = c * Vector((2 * cos(alpha), 
                    2 * sin(alpha), 
                    (a - b)))

    ob.location = v  
    ob.keyframe_insert('location', frame=frame)

    frame += entre_chaque_keyframe
```